# KineticJS on event pass variable

Tags: events, canvas, kineticjs

In jQuery it is possible to pass additional variables into the event to handle scope issues as below:

```
$('#element').click({index: i}, function(event){
    console.log(event.data.index);
});
```

How do I do this in KineticJS as the on event method doesnt provide this functionality? I managed to generate the circles using the array but cant seem to pass specific data to each event:

```
var data = [12.22, 34.45, 8.9];
var circles = [];

for(var i in data){
circles[i] = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x : Math.random() * stage.getWidth(),
    y : Math.random() * stage.getHeight(),
    radius : 4,
    fill : 'white'
});

circles[i].on('mousemove', {value: data[i]}, function() {
    console.log('need to use value for this particular event here');
});

shapesLayer.add(circles[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new attribute to circle and save the data value in it like this:

`circles[i].setAttr('dataVal',data[i]);`

and then you can access it in the event handler like this.

```
circles[i].on('mousemove', function() {
    console.log(this.getAttr(`dataVal`));
});
```

Comment: Great answer Ani, very helpful.  Thank you for posting.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Ani. As I posted the question I got to thinking that I could probably just "inject" a property into the object and access it like that. Your way is better from coding standard but the below also works even tho its crude:

```
circles[i].value = data[i];

circles[i].on('mouseover', function() {
    console.log(this.value);
});
```